# Possible effects of slurmstepd: error: Exceeded step memory limit at some point?

Tags: linux, slurm

I have a question for those of you familiar with the scheduler Slurm. Sometimes I get the following error message slurmstepd: error: Exceeded step memory limit at some point.

I know it means the memory allocated to my process wasn't enough. Nonetheless, the process isn't killed by the scheduler and often times it seems innocuous: The program runs to completion and the output files look in good shape.

Should I **always** assume that output is faulty and rerun the programs if I get that error message? Why sometimes the allocated memory can be exceeded but the program isn't killed?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you received a message that the job was killed by SLURM and sacct shows a completed status you should be reasonably able to assume that the job completed.

Comment: This is great news, but is there an explanation or references to support it? I've heard a lot of confusing information on this topic and I'd love an answer I can rely on.